# VSTO Outlook: Items.ItemAdd on Inbox, sent and draft folders -> Detect if it is fired as a result of a movement action caused by user

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I am trying to detect when an item is moved from one folder to another because in this use case I need to perform some actions. I need to detect when event is fired by a movement action caused by the user when he moves explicitly an item from one folder to another.

The problem is when Items.ItemAdd is fired for inbox, draft and sent folders because here I have a problem for these folders, I mean:

- In case of inbox: how can i detect if event is fired because it is a new message received (so not moved manually by the user) or if it is really moved by the user from another folder?

Same applies for other both folders, draft and sent:

- In case of draft: how can i detect if event is fired because Outlook automatically save a draft there by itself or if it is a movement action that user does from another folder?
- In case of sent: how can i detect if event is fired because Outlook itself has put there after sending an email, or if it is a movement action caused by the user when moving it from another folder?

also it would be applicable for other folders such as junk folder, how to detect if its a junk email received and put there by Outlook itself (not by user) or if the event is fired just because the user explicitly moved it to there?

What I am thinking about is just when the item is being moved, in the Folder_BeforeItemMove, set a property for the Outlook.MailItem, let's say for example, moved, so in the Items.ItemAdd I would check if that property exists for the Outlook.MailItem, if it exists then it is a movement caused explicitly by the user, otherwise, if this property does not exist, then the movement action to that folder has been caused by Outlook itself. Is that a good idea? of course, once the item is processed in the Items.ItemAdd event, i need to remove this property from the Outlook.MailItem.
y

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't recognize actions made manually and programmatically. Only tracking the sequence of actions can help you to detect the operation - whether a new item is received from the server (see the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class), autosaved (new items don't have EntryID property set until they are saved to the store and etc. The `BeforeItemMove` event can also help in distinguishing events made manually or not.

You are free to add any extra bits to items to distinguish actions, but I'd recommend recording an item's data instead, so the item will be unmodified. And when the `ItemAdd` event is fired you may compare the data recorded (from a collection  for example) and find whether the `BeforeItemMove` event was raised previously. Be aware, actions can be cancelled, so you may get one event and never the other. So, you need to flush that data at some point.

Comment: How can I modify Outlook.MailItem data so that the item remains as unmodified? I have tried  Outlook.MailItem.SetUserProperty but once you close Outlook a popup window is shown saying there are changes and If I want to save them. You recommended about recording an item's data, how can be this achieved? What function should I use?

Comment: You can maintain a collection of IDs, for example, a list of recently moved items.

Comment: Also after using SetUserProperty and my stuff done, i have tried mailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);. to return item to its original state before modifying it, but it does not work, popup window continues asking "Want to save your changes?" when I exit from Outlook. Why? it is supposed close undo all the changes and leave the item in its original state, or am i wrong? My active and open window is the explorer, not the inspector.

Comment: That's because you modified the item without calling the `Save` method.

Comment: Okay, so imagine that you backup the original state of your Outlook.MailItem, then you do the changes to it, and the you undo them. If you don't save it (doing Outlook.MailItem.Save) then Outlook detect the object has been changed and ask you for save changes when you exit Outlook application? But why? Okay, I have not saved it, but I have restored it to its original state so the Outlook.MailItem should be the same  despite I have not saved it.

Comment: Also, the same applies to the method Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard) which discards all the changes you did and leave MailItem in the original state so why then outlook ask for save changes on exit? This method does not save the object, okay I know, but If you touch something and then you restore it back to its original state, no changes should be detected despite it is not saved because the object remains exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% foolproof, but try to check if `MailItem.LastModificationTime` is close enough to `MailItem.CreationTime`. Don't compare the values to the local time since local and server clocks can be off.